# Can't open the generated pdf

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using the below code to download the value of a field as a pdf in jsf.

Though I am able to download the pdf but I am not able to open it.  It shows "can't open the pdf".

Is something wrong with the encoding here (tried giving UTF-8 in getbytes() but it didn;t work either.)?

```
public StreamedContent getGeneratePdf() throws IOException {
        final PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResponse();
        final HttpServletResponse res = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"letter.pdf\"");
        res.setHeader("Refresh", "1");
        res.flushBuffer();
        OutputStream output = res.getOutputStream();
        byte[] out=null;
        out=this.getNotes().getBytes();
        output.write(out);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        return null;
    }
```

notes is a property of type string which is populated from the UI.

Comment: String != PDF. You need to actually create a PDF document first. Only setting the content type will not do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Will do something about this.